# Improving the code to display also the values 0 or null

Tags: arcpy

The following code calculates the median in the grouped data. I run this code on my feature class with 18,000 features, but the Python IDLE only prints 10,000 results, that is, skips features for which the median cannot be calculated. I would like to improve this code so that Python IDLE also prints results for features for which the median cannot be calculated. For example, to print 0 or null values for these features.

```
import arcpy  
input_table = r'put the path to your table here'  
#lcb is the lower class boundary  
width_age_range_1 = 14.5  
lcb_age_range_1 = 0.0
width_age_range_2 = 50.0
lcb_age_range_2 = 14.5
width_age_range_3 = 35.5
lcb_age_range_3 = 64.5
median_list = [ ]  
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(input_table, ["TOT", "TOT_0_14",  "TOT_15_64", "TOT_65"]) as cursor :

for row in cursor :

    #if all numeric fields hopefully
    n_over2 = (row[0]/2.0)


    if row[1] >= n_over2 :
        #cumulative freq of groups before median group
        cumu_freq = 0.0
        if row[1] != 0.0 :
            median = lcb_age_range_1 + ( ((n_over2 - cumu_freq)/row[1]) * width_age_range_1)
            median_list.append(median)
            continue
        continue

    if (row[1] + row[2]) >= n_over2 :
        #cumulative freq of groups before median group
        cumu_freq = row[1] 
        if row[2] != 0.0 :
            median = lcb_age_range_2 + ( ((n_over2 - cumu_freq)/row[2]) * width_age_range_2)
            median_list.append(median)
            continue
        continue

    if (row[1] + row[2] + row[3]) >= n_over2 :
        #cumulative freq of groups before median group
        cumu_freq = row[1] + row[2]
        if row[3] != 0.0 :
            median = lcb_age_range_3 + ( ((n_over2 - cumu_freq)/row[3]) * width_age_range_3)
            median_list.append(median)
            continue
        continue

    else:
        median_list.append("error")  
for median in median_list :
print(median)  
#obviously can add a field and append these values in rather than printing them. look at arcpy.da.UpdateCursors
```

Comment: This code can't work as entered here -- The indent scheme is wrong. You also do not seem to have tried to test for NULL values (they're modeled as `None` in Python). You haven't provided some sample rows, so we can't evaluate the logic in your code (and the code itself seems unnecessarily complex to be an online code sample). Please tighten up your code, provide sample rows which demonstrate NULL data, and include your attempt to handle those values (with an indication of what's wrong.